# hibernate nested exception during database persistance

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm struggling with the following issue during insert records database.

> 2018-08-12 16:06:26.874  WARN 5482 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState:
>   HY000 2018-08-12 16:06:26.875 ERROR 5482 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'country_id' doesn't
>   have a default value Query is: insert into bi_person (additional_info,
>   gender_id, last_name, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?), parameters ['Java
>   master',48,'WW','John'] 2018-08-12 16:06:27.047 ERROR 5482 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      :
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [/bi-message-svc/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:
>   could not execute statement; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute
>   statement] with root cause
>
> org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Field 'country_id'
>   doesn't have a default value Query is: insert into bi_person
>   (additional_info, gender_id, last_name, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?),
>   parameters ['Java master',48,'WW','John']*

//coutry:

```
@Table(name = "bi_country")
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_country")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="country_book", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_country"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_person"))
    private Set<Person> persons;
```

//gender:

```
@Table(name = "bi_gender")
@Entity
public class Gender {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_gender")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

//person

```
@Table(name = "bi_person")
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "additional_info")
    private String additionalInfo;


    @ManyToOne
    private Gender gender;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Country> countries;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to carefully read the error message. It says:

> Field 'country_id' doesn't have a default value Query is: insert into bi_person (additional_info, gender_id, last_name, name) ...

So, your bi_person table has a field named `country_id`, which doesn't have any default value. And of course, Hibernate doesn't insert anything in that field since it doesn't have any such field in the entity Person. So you get that exception.

The database schema doesn't match with your entity design. Fix one, or the other, or both, and make sure they're compatible with each other.

If your database design, a person has **one** country (hence the column country_id in person). In your object design, a person has **many** countries.